# jQuery image scrolling script

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there any jQuery image scroller script similar to this one http://www.eogallery.com/ .

Like a carousel view, which show small thumbs in the side and big one in center. 
Eogallery is good but I need the three images to be scrolled at once not one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few listed here that might help you: http://sixrevisions.com/resources/14-jquery-plugins-for-working-with-images/ (This includes the one you mentioned.)

[jCarousel Lite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/index.php) looks promising. If I have understood your requirements correctly, [the documentation](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/index.php#doc) seems to stipulate that it can do what you want:

> **scroll**
>
> As of version 0.4.0, you can
> specify the number of items to scroll
> when you click the next or prev
> buttons. Ofcourse, this applies to the
> mouse-wheel and auto-scroll as well.
> For example, scroll:2 will scroll 2
> items at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the links.. We have done it using jCarousel and you can see it live here http://www.nestle-family.com/dessert-solutions/english/

Answer (score 2):

I feel these are the best carousel(s) as far as I know. may be they might help, give them a try

1) feature Carousel                : **http://www.bkosborne.com/featureCarousel.php**

2) waterwheel Carousel : **http://www.bkosborne.com/waterwheelCarousel.php**

Both Plugins belong to single author =)

Comment: Thanks.. excellent carousels.. but our current requirements is more in align with jCarousel (see the link posted above). Will be using the feature Carousel in another project soon..